# Excel 2016 locks up on VBA functions that worked in previous versions of Excel

Tags: vba, excel, crash

Here's a simplified version of the VBA code:

```
Option Explicit

Function LooBac(RawRan)

'   This VBA function locks up in Excel 2016.  It worked in previous
'   versions of Excel.

Dim oRawRanObj                  'The Raw Range
Dim iRawRanObjRow As Integer    'Number of Rows
Dim iRawRanObjCol As Integer    'Number of Columns
Dim Tem As Double               'Temp value

Dim i As Integer                'Counter
Dim j As Integer                'Counter

Application.Volatile

If TypeName(RawRan) <> "Range" Then

'       The Raw Range is not a range.

    LooBac = "*** An invalid RawRan range has been provided. ***"
    Exit Function

End If

'   Build an object using the structure of the Raw Range.

Set oRawRanObj = RawRan
iRawRanObjRow = oRawRanObj.Rows.Count
iRawRanObjCol = oRawRanObj.Columns.Count

'   This section seems to be the problem.
'   It appears to be related to the term oRawRanObj.Cells(j).Value

For i = 1 To 200
    For j = 1 To iRawRanObjRow
        Tem = oRawRanObj.Cells(j).Value
    Next j
Next i

LooBac = Tem

End Function
```

Set up the spreadsheet with the following:

1. Open a new blank Excel 2016 file.
2. Set the calculation mode to Manual.
3. Go to VBA and add the VBA code to a VBA Module.
4. Go to the blank spreadsheet and put a 1 in cell A1.
5. Put the formula =A1+1 in cell A2.
6. Copy cell A2 into all of the cells from A2 to A2400
7. In cell B25 put the formula =LooBac(A1:A25)
8. Copy cell B25 into all of the cells from B25 to B2400
9. Hit the F9 (recalc) button.

My machine will get to either 61% and hang, or will go to 85% and then Excel crashes.  Here are the specs on my machine:

1. Excel 2016 (32 bit)
2. Dell Inspiron 3847
3. Windows 10 Pro (64 bit)
4. Intel i7 3.6 GHz
5. 16 GB memory

I've read other threads where some users think Excel 2016 has a memory leak.  Other threads think something else might be going on.   Does anyone know of a solution for this type of problem?

Edit (12/29/2015) =============================================================

I got a couple of e-mails from people that have similar problems.  They asked how I got around the problem.  So, here it is.

In the above code (the original scheme), I replaced lines:

```
Dim oRawRanObj                  'The Raw Range
Dim iRawRanObjRow As Integer    'Number of Rows
Dim iRawRanObjCol As Integer    'Number of Columns

Set oRawRanObj = RawRan
iRawRanObjRow = Int(oRawRanObj.Rows.Count)
iRawRanObjCol = Int(oRawRanObj.Columns.Count)

Tem = oRawRanObj.Cells(j).Value
```

With the following lines:

```
Dim RawRanVal As Variant        'This was added to replace the Raw Range Object
Dim iRawRanValRow As Integer    'This was added to store the number of rows that are in RawRanVal

RawRanVal = RawRan.Cells.Value2
iRawRanValRow = UBound(RawRanVal, 1)

Tem = RawRanVal(j, 1)
```

The main difference in the new scheme versus the original scheme is that the new `RawRanVal` requires less memory than the original `oRawRanObj`.  When the UDF is copied into many cells (2375 cells in the example), the amount of wasted memory is much less with the new scheme.   Because this wasn't a problem with previous versions of Excel, my guess is that Excel 2016's garbage collection scheme is different than in previous versions of Excel.

In addition, using the original scheme, it was common for Excel's graphics to get screwed up.   Some percentage of Excel's cells would be displayed as gray and not show any numbers/characters.  I could still hit the down arrow and move into those cells (I could tell where I was because the formula bar would show the contents of each cell), but regardless of what I tried, the cells would not display normally.   Because of this, my guess is that Excel 2016 has an internal memory leak.

The last issue is that even though the new scheme allows me to continue to use my UDF's, the problem isn't really fixed.   With the new scheme, if I do nothing but recalc (F9) fifteen times, Excel 2016 will consistently give me an error message that says I'm out of memory.

The bottom line is, Excel sent back a message to Microsoft about half of the time when I was running the original scheme.   I'm assuming they'll put this in their list of bug fixes.

Comment: Does it do the same thing if you pass both the row and column to `.Cells` - ie `.Cells(j, i)`?

Comment: @Comintern If I use `.Cells(j, 1)`, it gets to 25% and hangs.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem (calculations complete), although it takes about 2 1/2 minutes to run.  My system specs are similar to yours, except computer is self-built, and processor is an i7-3770K @ 3.50 GHz.  Suggest you start Excel in Safe mode, so as to disable any addins that might be a problem.

Comment: @Ron  In Safe Mode, it hangs at 47%.     I also tried other changes.   If I change from `Integer` to `Dim iRawRanObjRow As Long` and `Dim iRawRanObjCol As Long` it will get to 100%, but Excel still crashes.

Comment: I don't know where else to look.  As we have almost identical hardware, OS and Excel versions, and it works OK here.  Perhaps start your computer using msconfig to disable everything except MS services, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Ron  Thanks for your effort.  I'll keep working on it.   For future reference, if I force an Integer calculation such as `iRawRanObjRow = Int(oRawRanObj.Rows.Count)`, it will get to 100%, but Excel still crashes.  In addition, after several crashes without a reboot, Excel told me that it was out of memory.   So, it's possible that the "memory leak" theory might be on the right track (at least on some machines).

Comment: Just looking at it, it doesn't make sense to me. what does `i` do? You are going to do the `j` loop 200 times for no reason. Also, you overwrite `Tem` the whole time, always going for the `Cell.Value`. Is this something like a "Benchmark"?

Comment: tested on Intel i5 1.90GHz, 8GB RAM, 64bit Win7, Excel 2007 32bit, completed without any issues.

Comment: Have you tried to add a `DoEvents` between the `Next j` and `Next i`?

Comment: @Dirk  The original code is 10 to 20 times the size of this simplified version.  I stripped out the parts that work.   The `i` counter was part of a more complicated section that I removed to make it easier to concentrate on the problem.  The same goes for the value `200` and `Tem`.  The purpose of the code is to make the problem obvious.

Comment: @KSSheon   Thanks for the effort.   The original code worked on Excel 2007, 2010, and 2013.   Excel 2016 is when the problem showed up.

Comment: but wouldn't it be WAY faster when you put the range into a variable like: `RawRanVal = RawRan.Values`? then use `RawRanVal` instead of the real cell...

Comment: @Dirk  I'm not sure what you mean.  The line `Set oRawRanObj = RawRan` copies the real cell into an object, and the object is used in the loop.    In your comment, what type of variable is `RawRanVal`?

Comment: `RawRanVal` would be a simple variant. running an array of values is extremely fast... simply put directly in front of `For i = 1 To 200` this: `Dim RawRanVal as Variant: RawRanVal = RawRan.Values`. then inside your loop simply change the line to `Tem = RawRanVal(1, j)` and check the time..

Comment: @DirkReichel The OPs code is designed to demo a problem, nothing more. There is no point in reviewing it here.  OP: dirk is right in that the code shows classic signs of an inefficient UDF.  If it works (does what you want, apart from the issue asked about here) it would be worth posting on CodeReview to get help improving it

Comment: At least, I didn't encounter any errors using his test... neither with 2013 nor with 2016...

Comment: @Dirk   I tried your method.    It worked.   However, while I was making the changes, Excel popped up with memory problems multiple times (requiring many reboots).    Keep in mind that the code as it is shown above is only a small part of the original UDF.   Because the original code ran without problems in Excel 2007, 2010, and 2013, it's really obvious that something has changed in Excel 2016.  Until I get more data, the "memory leak" theory seems to have good odds.

Comment: @Ron  It appears that the main difference in our machines (32 GB vs 16 GB) might be why the code works on your machine and not on mine.  I used Dirk's suggestion and got the UDF working again.  However, I noticed in the Task Manager that Excel's memory requirement kept rising every time I hit recalc.   After 15 recalcs, Excel tells me it's out of memory.  I rebooted and tried again.  At 15 recalcs, Excel is out of memory.  I doubt if the above code with 2400 references is enough to load up 32 GB, but you might use 30,000 references and hit recalc XX times to see if you get the same message.

Comment: @bill_080 I never wrote that I have 32GB.  I have 16GB, just like you.

Comment: just for the problem itself, try to loop `variable = Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi / 180` and `variable = Empty` about 1000000 times and watch the memory usage... there sure IS a problem with 2016 for win... still, I cant find a solve for this :/

Comment: @Ron  Oops, my mistake.

Comment: @Dirk   My guess is, Excel 2016 has changed the way they handle garbage collection.   In addition, there's a memory issue, and I don't know if that's an Excel problem or a Windows 10 problem.  For now, I'm going to limp along using your solution to the above problem.  Thanks.

Comment: You said, this doesn't happen for excel 2013... this way I don't think it's an issue to windows... (also other ppl had this problem regardless of win version)

Answer (score 0):

You use too many `variant` variable declaration.

What happens if a cell is #ERR , empty or non numeric?

```
Option Explicit

Function LooBac(byval RawRan AS RANGE) AS DOUBLE 'declare return value type too

Dim oRawRanObj AS RANGE                 'The Raw Range
Dim iRawRanObjRow As LONG       'Number of Rows
Dim iRawRanObjCol As LONG       'Number of Columns
Dim Tem As Double               'Temp value

Dim i As LONG                'Counter
Dim j As LONG                'Counter

Application.Volatile

If RawRan is nothing  Then 'i deleted this part if not change the condition


    'LooBac = "*** An invalid RawRan range has been provided. ***" 'really? at the end of the function it is a double and here a string !
Exit Function

End If

'   Build an object using the structure of the Raw Range.

Set oRawRanObj = RawRan
iRawRanObjRow = oRawRanObj.Rows.Count
iRawRanObjCol = oRawRanObj.Columns.Count

'   This section seems to be the problem.
'   It appears to be related to the term oRawRanObj.Cells(j).Value
dim h$
For i = 1 To iRawRanObjCol '@=200 (makes no sense else)
    For j = 1 To iRawRanObjRow
       h= oRawRanObj.Cells(j,I).Value '(just j makes no sense)
       IF ISNUMERIC(H) THEN 
          Tem = CDBL(H) 'change value to double
          'obviously some big part of the code is missing here, just looping and doing nothing with 'tem' is useless
           IF some condition is met THEN
              LooBac = Tem 
              EXIT FUNCTION
           END IF
       END IF
    Next j
Next i

'LooBac = Tem

End Function
```